# What does the term "distinguished basis" mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, terminology

I know what a basis is (talking about vector spaces here), but I don't know what a distinguished basis is. Can you please explain the difference to me?

I did not grow up in an English-speaking country and therefore have not had a math education in English. From googling the term I deduct that this seems to be a common concept amongst English mathematicians. So common in fact, that nobody ever cares to define it.

Comment: Really?  I've never even heard this term.  Can you give an example?

Comment: Could you provide a context in which you encountered this term?

Comment: "Distinguished" generally means something stand-out. There are many basis for a vector space, but in familiar ones there are usually a "natural" one that occurs. In $\mathbb{R}^n$ it could be the standard basis $\{e_1,\cdots,e_n\}$. In polynomials it could be $1,x,x^2,\cdots$. Those would be reasonably called "distinguished basis".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Distinguished basis** is a less common word for **orthogonal basis**

You can read about for example [here](http://archive.numdam.org/article/CM_1983__49_1_143_0.pdf)

**Quote**:

> The
>   theory
>   of
>   normed
>   spaces
>   over
>   a
>   trivially
>   valued
>   field
>   (or
>   valued
>   spaces)
>   was
>   developed
>   mainly
>   by
>   P.
>   Robert
>   in
>   his
>   series
>   of
>   papers
>   [3].
>   He
>   introduced
>   the
>   concept
>   of
>   distinguished
>   basis,
>   also
>   called
>   orthogonal
>   bases
>   in
>   the
>   literature,

Comment: Hey, that's good one!

Answer (score 0):

There is such thing as a distinguished monomial basis in linear algebra. Our professor talked about it, where the basis elements consists of monomials, being $1,x,x^2,x^3,...$
Could that perhaps be it?